# Converting code from Py3.0 to 2.7Py Super() and Print Statement

Tags: python, class

So I've got this piece of code from this nice guy at redblob games ( http://www.redblobgames.com/) and I'm having some difficulties converting his Py3.0 code to Py2.7.

The code can be found here. It is quite large so I get if you don't want to look at it: (http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.py)

If you can please suggest some changes I can make to it that would be greatly appreciated. Currently I've found 3 errors, 2 of which are syntax which I don't really understand.

---

Syntax 1

`def from_id_width(id, *, width):`

The error is the "*,"

---

Syntax 2

```
print("%%-%ds" % width % draw_tile(graph, (x, y), style, width), end="")
```

the error is the end=""

---

Type Error

```
class GridWithWeights(SquareGrid):
def __init__(self, width, height):
    super().__init__(width, height)
    self.weights = {}
```

`super()` takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

But when I put `GridWithWeights` in `super()`:

```
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Comment: Also note, in my experience, If you convert between Python 2 and 3, the most sly change is the integer division 3 / 2 = 1 (Python 2) vs 3 / 2 = 1.5 (Python 3). Best to use 3 // 2 if you want integer division in both versions.

Comment: @Matthias `from __future__ import division`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes you can import the Python 3 behavior. But I find it way easier (e.g. writing some commands in an interactive shell) to use another operator which you do not have to import every time. Furthermore, the import only changes behavior in Python 2 (in Python 3 this is the default) so this looks strange (in my opinion) in you want to have both Python 2 and 3 compatible code.

Comment: On the other hand one has to keep it always in mind when one wants to do an integer division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `from_id_width` to work you need to remove the keyword arg marker `*`:

```
def from_id_width(id, width):
   return (id % width, id // width)
```

`print` can be fixed with importing it from `__future__`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Finally `__init__` needs to call `super` bit differently:

```
class GridWithWeights(SquareGrid):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super(GridWithWeights, self).__init__(width, height)
        self.weights = {}
```

And the parent class must be converted to new style class:

```
class SquareGrid(object):
```